# Spark/Scala read hadoop file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In a pig script I saved a table using PigStorage('|').
I have in the corresponding hadoop folder files like

```
part-r-00000
```

etc.
What is the best way to load it in Spark/Scala ? In this table I have 3 fields: Int, String, Float

I tried:

```
text = sc.hadoopFile("file", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], sc.defaultMinPartitions)
```

But then I would need somehow to split each line. Is there a better way to do it?

If I were coding in python I would create a Dataframe indexed by the first field and whose columns are the values found in the string field and coefficients the float values. But I need to use scala to use the pca module. And the dataframes don't seem that close to python's ones

Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

PigStorage creates a text file without schema information so you need to do that work yourself something like

```
sc.textFile("file") // or directory where the part files are  
val data = csv.map(line => {
   vals=line.split("|")
   (vals(0).toInt,vals(1),vals(2).toDouble)}
)
```

Comment: You can split in haddopFile as ... 

      val dataRDD = sc.hadoopFile("wc2.txt", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text],sc.defaultMinPartitions).map(pair => pair._2.toString).map(r => r.split("|"))